# jQuery - how to access a object displayed by Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a content loaded by jQuery .load() function:

```
<input type="text" name="street2" id="street2" value="" class="text" />
```

I have a simple jQuery handler to add value into the input tag on focus:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    $( "#street2" ).focus(function(){
        $( "#street2" ).val($( "#address" ).val());
    });
});
```

The JS code was loaded with other scripts on first load when object #street2 didn't exist. Therefore it didn't work.

I have tried to load the script with different ways directly after Ajax was performed but with no success.
Could you advice me how to handle new objects with jQuery?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried event delegation ("Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future")?

```
$(document).on('focus', '#street2', function(){
    $('#street2').val($('#address').val());
});
```

With event delegation: http://jsfiddle.net/8HHTM/

Without (like your current code): http://jsfiddle.net/8HHTM/1/

Comment: Thanks for a real example. It works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery binds the focus event to all elements that match the selector '#street' when the dom is ready. However, when the dom is ready, the ajax call is not yet completed, so there are no elements matching your selector.

To make sure the event is bound to all instances of the selector (also future ones that are not yet added to the DOM), use the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FkhHD/

Comment: Perfect. No I haven't try on() function before. Thanks for the explanation.